# $X,Y$ distributes geometrically, calculate $P(X+Y=n)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have this question (Answer provided).

[image: Q&A]

I'm asking only about $P(X+Y=n)$

My calculation is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n P(X = k, Y = n-k) $$ 
And when calculated like this, the final answer is: $(n+1) p^2 (1-p)^n$

I've searched online and found that in a lot of places $(n-1)$ will recieved if the sigma is: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}$$ So it might be the key to the answer.

BUT, I don't have any constraints in the question so why should it be like this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two different definitions of Geometric distribution (check wikipedia or anything else). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

You use the one which starts from zero, authors of this problem use the one that starts from 1.

Comment: I saw that P(X=k) can be with exp of k-1 for k = 1, 2, 3, .... or with exp of k for k = 0, 1, 2... 

BUT in this question it doesn't metter, because it will be the same values in the numerator and in the denominator, evantually it will be reduced. 

The first thing I did was to change my formula to use both, k/k-1, it didn't change my answer (1/(n=1))

Comment: If you use the one that starts from 1 you get exactly $1/(n-1)$.

Comment: P(X+Y = n) = $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1-p)^(k-1) * p * (1-p)^(n-k+1) * p = n * (1-p)^n * p^2 $$
What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnSnowTheDeveloper If $X$ is at least 1, then $Y$ is at most $n-1$.

Comment: OK I get it, But why do we prevent X from getting the value 0? 
The question didn't have this constraint. 
Why P(X=0, Y=n) or P(X=n, Y=n) isn't possible?

Comment: May be authors of that problem specified earlier that they use geometric distribution starting from 1 or smth like that.

Answer (score -1):

The geometric distribution has probability mass zero on $0$.  Consequently, 
$$ P(X = 0, Y = n) = P(X = n, Y = 0) = 0  \text{.}  $$

Therefore, your 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n P(X = k, Y = n-k) = 0 + \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} P(X = k, Y = n-k) \right)  + 0  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Why P(X=0, Y=n) = 0 ? 
For example, P(X=0) = $(1-p)^0 * p$
And P(X=0, Y=n) =  $(1-p)^0 * p * (1-p)^n*p $

Comment: @JohnSnowTheDeveloper : "The [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) has probability mass zero on $0$" is why.  This is explicit in omitting $0$ and $n$ from "$U(1,n-1)$".